# Drawbacks of system-site-packages?

Tags: python, python-venv

An advantage of using the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) option `--system-site-packages` is that it avoids having multiple copies of a given package on one’s system, when several packages rely on the same version of that package (especially handy with big and common packages such as pandas, numpy or tensorflow).

Beyond Python and in general, it seems to me to make sense for reasons of simplicity and economy of resources, when several services on my system rely on some-given-data-source-or-program, to store the data or program once in a central place and refer every service to that central place, rather than copying it all around multiple times (assuming here that the data is used solely as a source and not written to, otherwise other considerations come into play). I think that this is the generally accepted state of mind; for example, in Debian, when I use `apt` to install a package `p` that depends on package `d`, `apt` will check if `d` is installed already and not download it again if so.

I view the option `--system-site-packages` as implementing this idea of “put my common dependency somewhere only once and let everyone use that common spot”. But, given that it is not the default option, I suspect that there are problems with this. Thus, I wonder about the *disadvantages* of using `--system-site-packages`. Why and when should I *not* use it? In other words, if I use it systematically without thinking further, when will I run into trouble?

Note that I am *not* asking why using virtual environments make sense in general: I understand that they enable concurrent usage of packages whose sets of dependencies are incompatible with each other. I am asking for the drawbacks of using virtual environments systematically *with the option `--system-site-packages`*, versus using virtual environments systematically without that option.

Comment: Using packages from the system Python goes against the whole idea of using a venv. The system installer might change things, or install in a non-standard way, or upgrade a library version. In a venv you want to know that you have exactly the packages you want, that you also have control over.

Comment: I am imagining using virtual environments in the (I believe) standard way, meaning, together with a list of dependencies (with version numbers) that my program rely on, and a system, such as `hatch`, that downloads any missing dependency before running the program. (I thought that it goes without saying but I can edit my post if it is useful.)